# How to group Get-ChildItem -Recurse results in one output table?

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following Powershell command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt
```

But if there's multiple results the output will be like this:

```
    Directory: C:\TestFolder\myfolder\

Mode          LastWriteTime   Length Name
----          -------------   ------ ----
-a---     d/m/yyyy hh:MM PM   1234   dragons.txt

    Directory: C:\TestFolder\anotherfolder\

Mode          LastWriteTime   Length Name
----          -------------   ------ ----
-a---     d/m/yyyy hh:MM PM   66550  jabberwocky.txt
```

But I *want* to get grouped results in some form.

Maybe like this:

```
Mode          LastWriteTime   Length Directory                     Name
----          -------------   ------ ---------                     ----
-a---     d/m/yyyy hh:MM PM   1234   C:\TestFolder\myfolder\       dragons.txt
-a---     d/m/yyyy hh:MM PM   66550  C:\TestFolder\anotherfolder\  jabberwocky.txt
```

Or this:

```
Length  FullPath
------  --------
1234    C:\TestFolder\myfolder\dragons.txt
66550   C:\TestFolder\anotherfolder\jabberwocky.txt
```

You probably get the idea. How can I accomplish this, preferably in a simple and elegant manner?

I tried `Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | Format-Table` but that doesn't do much. I've also checked the most relevant similar questions suggested by Stack Overflow (i.e. "[Recurse with PowerShell's Get-ChildItem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23976146/419956)", and others), but haven't been able to distill a solution so far.

---

**Addendum**:

I used `help group` and found that `group` is actually the exact alias for the Cmdlet I thought I was looking for: `Group-Object`. If I do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | Group-Object "FullName"
```

I get:

```
Count   Name           Group
-----   --------       -----
    1   C:\TestFold... {C:\TestFolder\myfolder\dragons.txt}
    1   C:\TestFold... {C:\TestFolder\anotherfolder\jabberwocky.txt}
```

But this requires me to simplify with *an additional step* to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | Group-Object "FullName" | Select-Object "Name"
```

Which gets:

```
Name
----
C:\TestFolder\myfolder\dragons.txt
C:\TestFolder\anotherfolder\jabberwocky.txt
```

If I *really* want extra properties, then I guess I want to "group on *multiple* properties", making the question effectively a duplicate of [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30769809/419956).

However, all this "grouping" seems like overkill. Is there not a direct way of using `Get-ChildItem` to get the output I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PowerShell has its own way of displaying `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` and `System.IO.FileInfo` objects. If you don't want to see that then you just need to use `Select-Object`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\temp | select Mode,LastWriteTime,Length,Directory,Name
```

`Group-Object` is completely unnecessary. Given your need I suppose `Group-Object` seemed appealing but its power is not needed here like it is used for in the linked question. What you really wanted to do is change how PowerShell deals with those objects. `Format-Table` does not work for the same reason. It was taking the PowerShell by design output and making a table. If you called the properties with `Format-Table` you would have the same solution as we did with `Select-Object`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse c:\temp | Format-Table Mode,LastWriteTime,Length,Directory,Name
```

Please... Please... don't use that line if you intend to use the output in other functions. Format-cmdlets break objects and are used for the purpose of *displaying* data only.

Comment: Thank you very much! Glad I decided to post after all. I now see that my "answer" was actually a bad workaround, I've deleted that "answer" and slipstreamed it into my question (as it would not invalidate your answer in any way). Thx again for the simpler solution.

Comment: I just want to add, for search purposes, that you need to do this if you want to sort the child items all as one block, since otherwise they'll still be grouped by parent directory. For example, `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select FullName,LastWriteTime | sort LastWriteTime` is how you get all items sorted by LastWriteTime regardless of what directory they're in.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to get a list of files recursively with their fullpath names, don't use Group or Select.  All of these Commands pretends to be a spreadsheet of objects displayed in a text console.

Instead use the foreach-object operator "%{ }" to dump the raw string date to the console.  Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | %{ $_.fullname }
```

(Incidentally the above is equivalent to linux command: "find .")

If you want to see which fields are accessible from the foreach-object script block.  you can issue this command:

```
Get-ChildItem my_filepath  | get-member
```

Alternatively, you could pipe the output of Get-ChildItem to Export-Csv command and open it in notepad.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -file *.txt | 
Select FullName | 
Export-Csv "files.csv"

notepad files.csv
```

Alternatively, use cmd:

```
cmd /c dir /b /s *.txt
```